# When pip install 'pyrebase', I got error ' UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 500: illegal multibyte sequence'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
Collecting jws>=0.1.3 (from python-jwt==2.0.1->pyrebase)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/9e/1536d578ed50f5fe8196310ddcc921a3cd8e973312d60ac74488b805d395/jws-0.1.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Wesely\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w5z8dsub\jws\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        long_description=read('README.md'),
      File "C:\Users\Wesely\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w5z8dsub\jws\setup.py", line 5, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 500: illegal multibyte sequence

    ----------------------------------------
```

I tried easy_install pyrebase, and using virtualenv.

I'm using Korean Windows 10.

Comment: It looks that you use python 3 - so you need to install pyrebase of python 3 - not 2

Comment: I used pip based on python3

Comment: and pyrebase is developed for python3 env

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just solved this. 
[MyGitHub.io](https://wesely.github.io/pip,%20python,%20pip/Fix-'cp950'-Error-when-using-'pip-install'/)

It's a bug from `jws` package, it should consider the encoding problem in its `setup.py`.

My Solution : install `jws` first

- use `pip download jws` instead of `pip install`
- use 7z open the `filename.tar.gz` archive
- edit the `setup.py` file
- change this line

```
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
```

to

```
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname), encoding="UTF-8").read()
```

- Re-archive the tar file, run pip install `filename.tar`

After `jws` being installed, run `pip install pyrebase`.
It should work.

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer if the problem been solved :D ?

Comment: Sorry for accepting answer late. I am not used to stack overflow.

Comment: I believe there might be an error on the answer. "encoding="UTF-8").read()" part is pasted twice. last part should be deleted. if not it gives a syntax error. This would be the final version: return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname), encoding="UTF-8").read()

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting Visual Studio Community 2017 including python dev. option

Comment: Perhaps a more in depth answer would help future users. This is still pretty unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by

1. moving the python-jwt install up in the order of my `requirements.txt`
2. not specifying an older version of python-jwt encoded in pyrebase

One of those did the trick.